# Comparing Dates in NodeJS IF Statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using nodejs/javascript and trying to compare two dates to each other in order to apply a specific style if the date is before the set date.

Here is what I have:

```
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getMonth()+1+'/'+d.getDate()+'/'+(d.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)-1);

var da = new Date('1/4/18');
var da_test = da.getMonth()+1+'/'+da.getDate()+'/'+(da.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2));

if(da_test < date) {
    // do something
}
```

`date_test` is currently returning the date from a year ago today, `1/23/18`. I have set the other date that it will compare itself to, to `1/4/18`. While this should be true, for some reason it is not whenever the IF statement runs. However, if I change the date to something like `1/2/18`, then it returns true. How is that the case and how can it be changed so it will return true if it is any date before 1/23/18?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare those two dates like this:

```js
const d1 = new Date('1/23/18');
const d2 = new Date('1/4/18');
if (d2 < d1) ...
```

In your code example you are comparing two `String`s

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something simple, just couldn't put my finger on it

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the milliseconds since epoch (the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00)

```
const d1 = new Date('1/23/18');
const d2 = new Date('1/4/18');

if (d2.getTime() < d1.getTime()) {
}
```

You can also compare ISO date strings

```
const d1 = new Date('1/23/18');
const d2 = new Date('1/4/18');

if (d2.toISOString() < d1.toISOString()) {
}
```